# Insertion Sort with two arrays

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I need to implement the insertion sort, but i have to use another array called temp. In this array must be copied the values of starting arrays in the right position

I've tried to implement the insertion sort algorithm with some modifications i thought to do the task

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] a) {
    int[] temp = new int[a.length];
    for(int indice = 0; indice < a.length; indice++) {
        int key = a[indice];
        int j = indice - 1;

        while(j>=0 && a[j] > key) {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j = j-1;
        }
        a[j+1] = temp[j+1];
    }
}
```

I've tried to use it with an array with this numbers: 5, 1, 4, 14, 21, 144, 3
But it is printed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: What do you use `temp` for?

Comment: I use temp as the second array in which to put values in the correct order

Comment: No you don't. That why I asked the question, for you to check your code.

Comment: If you want insertion sort, implement insertion sort. See algorithm on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort, or anywhere else. `int[] temp` is just not there.

Comment: Or, if you want to return an ordered copy of the input array: 1) make sure that you use `temp` everywhere, except when you make the copy at the beginning 2) also return it (returning `void` will not do the job).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the temp array, but you're not assigning any value to any position. So when you do "a[j+1] = temp[j+1];" there's nothing in that array so it assigns 0 to a[j+1].

If I got it right, temp must be a copy of a so you can do something like this:

```
int[] temp = new int[a.length]; 

for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) 
{ 
    temp[i] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: Right after the initialization of temp. Assuming that you want temp to be a copy of a

Comment: Now with your piece of code works perfectly. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as resolved with the answer, it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using temp array. No assignment done to temp. It has empty array.

Try below and should sort the array as you want

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 5, 1, 4, 14, 21, 144, 3 };

        int[] arr2 = insertionSort(a);
        for(int i:arr2){
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }

 public static int[] insertionSort(int[] input){    
         int temp;
         for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
             for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
                 if(input[j] < input[j-1]){
                     temp = input[j];
                     input[j] = input[j-1];
                        input[j-1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return input;
        }
```